# jquery ajax load images from local folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get pictures from a local folder and post them on a webpage.

Pictures aren't loading on webpage but no errors in console.

```
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var dir = "/Users/me/Desktop/imgtest/";
        var fileextension = ".jpeg";
        $.ajax({
            url: dir,
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                    var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
                    $("body").append("<img src='" + dir + filename + "'>");
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Have you tried `dir = "file:///Users/me/Desktop/imgtest/"`?

Comment: @KarlReid Still not working.

Comment: Javascript runs in a browser and **must not have access** to local resources. Else it would be a huge security loophole.

Comment: how would your http **server** interpret `/Users/me/Desktop/imgtest/` - what will it return if you request such an URL?

Comment: @JaromandaX it loads my files from that folder.  When I click on the html file, nothing appears.

Comment: so a `GET /Users/me/Desktop/imgtest/` returns the files (I assume it's a list of files, not the contents of said files) from that folder, and that works? is that `file:///Users/me/Desktop/imgtest/` or `http://Users/me/Desktop/imgtest/`

Answer (score 0):

***This can't be running cos you page isn't loading.***
You should add this script before the end of your body or use `$(document).ready` to be sure you page is loading before to call the Ajax script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var dir = "/Users/me/Desktop/imgtest/";
        var fileextension = ".jpeg";
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: dir,
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                    var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
                    $("body").append("<img src='" + dir + filename + "'>");
                });
            }
        });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: This for the security reason, is normal you should add canvas or convert your image to base64 to be properly loading without any risk of security... https://www.base64-image.de/ how to load base64 image here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: I'll try those.  I have a lot of jpegs in the folder, so converting could be time consuming to do manually.  Canvas didn't work.

Comment: @ntf So do it with my own tool you can take it easy multiples uploaded convert to base64 here https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/BwEWxE

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look, but might be too advanced for me right now.  Still a beginner.

Comment: Don't worries stackoverflow is your home if you meet the good peoples ;).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your script code in a document ready function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // your code here
});
```

Then, run a local web server to avoid XSS issues.

Comment: Tried it with Chrome Web Server.  Got error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Which resource was not found?